# How can I open the current GitHub branch on Web using Windows command line?

Tags: windows, github, command-line-interface, conemu

I had this command working on my Mac/Linux (Terminal) with OhMyZsh, but once I moved to Windows, I wasn't sure how to update it using Cmdr/ConEmu shell.

Basically, I want an alias that is like "goweb" that will open my default browser to the current branch on GitHub. I'm fine assuming a particular repo. Maybe a later enhancement would pull that as well using, e.g., default remote or the like..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer hard-codes the repo URL and just appends the current branch. Add this to your user-aliases.cmd (if using cmdr) or wherever you can set aliases.

```
goweb=@echo off && for /f %i in ('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD') do start https://<pathToRepo>/tree/%i
```

Replace  with the URL to your repo.

Once this is in there, you can just type `goweb` from your CLI and it should open it for ya. Saves a few clicks when you need to do something on your current branch on GH.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use the GitHub command-line `gh`, specifically [`gh browse`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_browse), introduced with Gh 1.12.0 (June 2021)

> Open the GitHub repository in the web browser.
>
> ```
> gh browse [<number> | <path>] [flags]
> ```
>
> Example
>
> ```
> $ gh browse main.go --branch main
> # => Open main.go in the main branch
> ```

If you just want the remote URL, add the [`--no-browser` option](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/3943).

[GitHub CLI 2.1.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.1.0) (oct. 2021) brings a feature to open the latest commit of a branch in `gh browse`

```
  -c, --commit                   Open the last commit
```

> `--branch` supports SHAs, `-n` prints only a URL, and `-c l`inks t o the latest commit.